# Matlab: using avifile, addframe, getframe; the generated avi is contorted

Tags: matlab, video, screen-capture, avi

I'm training a machine learning algorithm, and wanted to make an avi to visualize the appearance of weights over time.  I threw together something similar to:

```
aviobj = avifile( 'weights.avi' );
for jj = 1:whatever
  % do some training
  imagesc( ... ); % where '...' is stuff to reshape the weight matrix
  aviobj = addframe( aviobj, getframe );
end;
aviobj = close( aviobj );
implay( 'weights.avi' );
```

The problem is, the frames end up looking like this:
[image]

The numbers shouldn't have that orientation.  This occurs with any avi I generate in matlab.

Any suggestions?

-Brian

Comment: how are you generating your frames? It looks like each row is being circularly shifted by the row index.

Comment: I'm generating the frames with `imagesc`.  The parameter is just a (reshaped) weight matrix.  However, your comment gave me an idea.  The picture I've posted here I chose for the sake of giving something indisputably messed up, whereas the weight visualization someone might've considered normal.  The weights are similarly skewed, but there's a single black line that cuts from top right to bottom left.  I bet it's adding an extra column of pixels to the output frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally had time to get back to this.  The problem was due to the axes.  When using something like `image` or `imagesc`, it tacks on an extra black border line on the bottom & left of the image.  When you use `getframe`, it grabs only the image data plotted, sans the black lines.  However, the frame itself is slightly larger than the image data.

The following solves it:

```
aviobj = avifile( 'weights.avi' );
fig = figure;
for jj = 1:whatever
  % do some training
  imagesc( ... ); % where '...' is stuff to reshape the weight matrix
  axis off;
  aviobj = addframe( aviobj, getframe( fig ) );
end;
aviobj = close( aviobj );
implay( 'weights.avi' );
```

Setting `axis off` fixes it.